# Handling '+' in ASP Net Core routes

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, url-routing

How are '+' handled in ASP Net Core routes? 
I have a route defined like this:

`"/Test/{words}/{type:regex(^(AA|BB|CC)$)}/{search2}"`

with parameters of the function being string[] words, string type, string search2

With different URLS:

- `/Test/word1+word2/AA/blablabla` => 404
- `/Test/word1%20word2/AA/blablabla` => Ok, words={"word1 word2"}
- `/Test/word1,word2/AA/blablabla` => Ok, words={"word1","word2"}

I don't understand the 404. any idea why it happens? I would have translated the '+' with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must encode a space; it is correct to encode a space as +, but only in the query string; in the path you must use %20. For + you can use %2b. (Http 1.1)

Comment: Ok, the URL should not contain any '+' character. Thanks